# How to return header of a column which satisfy certain condition to new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

for below dataframe,how to return header name of column which is greater than 1 to new column named "Remark"

```
    A   B   C   
0   1   1   2   
1   2   2   2   
2   1   3   1
3   4   5   2
```

Desired Out put as below

```
    A   B   C   Remark
0   1   1   2   C
1   2   2   2   A,B,C 
2   1   3   1   B
3   4   5   2   A,B,C
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) of boolean `DataFrame` by columns names with separator and last remove `,`:

```
df['Remark'] = df.gt(1).dot(df.columns + ',').str[:-1]
print (df)
   A  B  C Remark
0  1  1  2      C
1  2  2  2  A,B,C
2  1  3  1      B
3  4  5  2  A,B,C
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.gt(1))
       A      B      C
0  False  False   True
1   True   True   True
2  False   True  False
3   True   True   True

print (df.gt(1).dot(df.columns + ','))
0        C,
1    A,B,C,
2        B,
3    A,B,C,
dtype: object
```